# how to creat list than contain a specific number

Tags: python, list, append

If numlist contains a list of numbers, create a new list that contains only
those numbers that are less than 100.

(e.g. [42, 130, 7, 100, 101] becomes [42, 7])

I tried this but my output is "1,4" only

Can you help me on this, it's even better if you find another way rather rather than using the while loop

```
numlist = [1,4,200,56,78,900,433,555,554]
numlist2 = []
i=0
while numlist[i] < 100:
    numlist2.append(numlist[i])
    i = i+1

print(numlist2)
```

Comment: I suggest you google `filter a list in python` and check out some of the possibilities.

Comment: This condition: `numlist[i] < 100` will be truth until the loop reaches the third element of `numlist`, which is 200 (i.e, greater than 100). That's why you only get 1 and 4 appended to `numlist2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be overthinking this. Just iterate over the elements of `numlist` with a `for` loop and check your condition. No need for integer indexes or a `while`.

Oneliner:

```
numlist2 = [x for x in numlist if x < 100]
```

"Traditional"

```
numlist2 = []
for x in numlist:
    if x < 100:
        numlist2.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numlist2 = list(filter(lambda x: x < 100, numlist))
```

Comment: why use `filter` if you are just going to wrap it in a `list` call afterwards anyways. `[x for x in numlist if x < 100]` would be more Pythonic anyways.